# GMail like selection combobox implemented in GWT

Tags: gwt, combobox

I'm interested in implementing something like the combobox used in GMail to easily select emails. The "default" selection of the combobox has a checkbox that can be clicked to select all emails, otherwise you can dropdown the box and choose another selection option.

[image]
How would you go about implementing this in GWT?

Comment: You can use Chrome's Developer Tools (or Firebug) to inspect the DOM around that area, to get an idea of how the elements are arranged. From there you can mimic that in a UIBinder template. I don't have any specific ideas, but that's how I'd start working on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class SelectionComboBox extends HorizontalPanel implements ClickHandler {
    private class ListItem extends Label implements ClickHandler {
        String text;
        public ListItem(String text) {
            this.text = text;
            this.setText(text);
            this.addClickHandler(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            selectedValue = text;
            popup.hide();
        }
    }

    CheckBox combo;
    FlowPanel list;
    PopupPanel popup;
    String selectedValue;
    Label triangle;

    public SelectionComboBox() {
        list = new FlowPanel();
        popup = new PopupPanel();
        combo = new CheckBox();
        triangle = new Label();
        list.add(new ListItem("All"));
        list.add(new ListItem("None"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Read"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Unread"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Starred"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Unstarred"));
        popup.setWidget(list);
        popup.setPopupPosition(this.getAbsoluteLeft(),
            this.getAbsoluteTop() + this.getOffsetHeight());
        this.addDomHandler(this, ClickEvent.getType());
        triangle.addClickHandler(this);
        this.add(combobox);
        this.add(triangle);
    }

    public void addValueChangeHandler(ValueChangeHandler<Boolean> handler) {
        combo.addValueChangeHandler(handler);
    }

    public String getSelection() {
        return selectedValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        popup.show();
    }
}
```

Style for the triangle:

```
height:0;
width:0;
border-left:20px solid transparent;
border-right:20px solid transparent;
border-top:20px solid black;
```

The above styles will give you a triangle just using Css.

You might have to add a feature that will not select the Checkbox if the list hasn't elements that apply to the selection.

(Note: Code is untested, but should help you get started)

Comment: I had to do something similar and took similar approach.  The subtleties are in getting the keyboard to work as well.

Comment: I tried out the code, its reasonably close, but the main issue I don't see how to "fix". As the code is now, clicking on the checkbox pops-up the choices, instead, it should only show the choice on clicking the arrow, clicking the checkbox should select/deselect all the table rows with no pop-up selection. Do I use an image or somesuch to trigger the listbox?

Comment: Remove this line: `this.addDomHandler(this, ClickEvent.getType());` and it will only popup the list if you click the arrow. Style the Label named triangle with the style I have provided and you get a arrow just using css which is smaller than an image,